# OSError when using selenium in multiple scripts simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, selenium, web-scraping

I am running several Python scripts at the same time on Windows, each using Selenium to get data from the web. If I run only one of them individually, all works well. But when run together, I keep getting the following error:

> OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

and it always comes at a line that uses the [`find_element_by_tag_name`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) function of [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Here is an example of a full traceback. It's a bit long, but it shows that it is occuring when trying to run the [socket.connect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) method. Any advice on why this is occuring and how I can achieve my goal of simultaneously running Python scripts that use Selenium?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-ba99a1a73a3a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/testFolder/test.py', wdir='D:/testFolder')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/testFolder/test.py", line 40, in <module>
    files = [file.find_element_by_tag_name('a') for file in files]

  File "D:/testFolder/test.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
    files = [file.find_element_by_tag_name('a') for file in files]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 230, in find_element_by_tag_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value=name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 516, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 499, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 295, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 487, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)

OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Comment: How do you run them? Need to see the script also to understand better

Comment: Thank @TarunLalwani, what do you mean by "how"? I am working within one instance of Spyder, running each script in a different Kernels. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I meant I would like to see the script you are executing